# WebView cannot load webpage inside

Tags: android, url, android-fragments, webview, android-webview

I wanna load webpage inside fragment, but there is some problem.

1.without `overriding` `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method, the website is open with default browser Chrome.

2.when overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, nothing happens. just new blank activity is created.
This is my `onCreateView` method inside `Fragment` class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View resultView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container, container, false);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        String url  = getArguments().getString(KEY_URL);

        WebView productDetailView = (WebView)resultView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        productDetailView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });

        productDetailView.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return resultView;
}
```

`targetSdkVersion` is `19` and added `INTERNET` permission and XML file of Fragment is like below.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ProductDetailFragment">


    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

});
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

and start your activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: Hmm.. OK. Try start your activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Answer (score 0):

```
      webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    webView.setSaveEnabled(false);
    String receivedName = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("USERNAME");
    Log.d("receivedName ----- ", receivedName);
    webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" +  
          receivedName);
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
          Webview.this.finish();
            }
    });
```

Try this code...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(ActivityA.this, "", "Loading...", true);  
     wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
     wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     wv.loadUrl("<url");
     wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         @Override
         public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
         {
             pd.show();
         }
         @Override
         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
             pd.dismiss();
                 }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
 into Manifest file ?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html